# Redirect all requests to /web/file_*

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, web

in my web directory i have files like:

> file_one
>     file_two
>     file_three

Right now, Iam using .htaccess with:

```
redirect /web/file_three  http://www.example.com
```

If Id want to redirect all the file_ request Id have to use 3 lines in .htaccess - one for each of file_

Can I use something like:

```
redirect /web/file_*  http://www.example.com
```

- redirect everything that starts with "file_"

Comment: Downvote without answer, why? 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found an answer.
If you want to redirect all request that starts/ends with given text string use:

```
redirectMatch /web/file_(.*) http://www.example.com
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question right, this should work.

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/web/file_(.*)$  http://www.example.com [R=301,L]

Comment: Havent tried your soluting but found another one that works. Posted it as answer.